# How do I install a GUI on the Ubuntu server 17.04

Tags: gui

I do not know how to get past this screen.
I tried to find a solution on the Internet but I only found how to install a desktop but that doesn't work because I need to install the GUI first.

Please help,
Kind regards 
Cas Muijsers

Answer (score 0):

The ubuntu-desktop package is a metapackage which will include X11 (the GUI.)

A metapackage is a virtual package that will install a collection of other packages.

Once you log into the text console run:  `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

The following link will show you the packages it will install.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-desktop

Comment: I solved the problem thanks for your comment gdahlm.